# Definition for organic tag

Tags: discussion, tags

(Prompted by [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/5727/how-environmentally-friendly-is-palm-oil-with-an-organic-label)) The [organic](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic) tag has no definition here yet.

What definition can we come up with?

Things to consider:

- If there are no legal definitions, labeling something *organic* can just be greenwashing. So any restrictions on the way this term is allowed to be used (labeling, packaging) could be a good starting point.
- This is an international site.

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following tag definition:

*Organic is a label placed on food products and clothing that are produced according to organic farming principles. The exact meaning of organic differs per country and/or certification-scheme, but usually it means produced without the use of artificial fertilizers and artifical pesticides, and with ecological balance, animal welfare and biodiversity in mind.*

In the tag wiki we can provide a short list of the larger and more common schemes such as Europe's biological/organic scheme and USDA. Perhaps we can even add something about the main differences between them.

Comment: I've used the text above to create a first version of the tag wiki

Comment: a query - does organic production allow the use of natural pesticides? If not, it might be better to alter the order of words. As the definition is currently written organic excludes artificial pesticide but it might allow for natural pesticides to be used. If no pesticides are permitted then maybe the definition should be changed to "The exact ... produced without the of pesticides and artificial fertilizers, ..."

Comment: @Fred Yes, organic allows natural pesticides. I'll edit to make it more clear.